# How to get the current date weekly day wise in angular 8 or javascript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am working for a whether forcast project.I need to get the current date weekly day wise in angular 8 or javascript only for 5 days related to previous and next of current day. Suppose today is saturday so it will display the date of last thursday,friday, today's date of saturday, upcoming date of sunday and monday. Here is the code below

### home.component.html

```
<div style="float:left">
    <p>Thu</p>
    <p>4</p>
</div>
<div style="float:left;margin-left:10px;">
    <p>Fri</p>
    <p>5</p>
</div>
<div style="float:left;margin-left:10px;">
    <p>Sat</p>
    <p>6<p>
</div>
<div style="float:left;margin-left:10px;">
    <p>Sun</p>
    <p>7</p>
</div>
<div style="float:left;margin-left:10px;">
    <p>Monday</p>
    <p>8</p>
</div>
```

### home.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  getListData: any;
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {

  }
}
```

Comment: Your question is ambiguous and needs some clarification. consider providing some expected outputs and elaborate a bit.

Comment: I have updated the description please check it

Answer (score 0):

You cam simply create the 2 days before and keep on increasing the date  and create the list for the same and pass on the list to your `homeComponent`

```
let daysList = [];
  const d = new Date();

  // set the date to two days ealrier, then keep on increaing it
  d.setDate(d.getDate() - ((d.getDay() + 3) % 7));
  daysList.push(new Date(d.getFullYear(), d.getMonth(), d.getDate())); 
  daysList.push(new Date(d.getFullYear(), d.getMonth(), d.getDate() + 1));
  daysList.push(new Date(d.getFullYear(), d.getMonth(), d.getDate()+2));
  daysList.push(new Date(d.getFullYear(), d.getMonth(), d.getDate()+3));
  daysList.push(new Date(d.getFullYear(), d.getMonth(), d.getDate() + 4));
```

Comment: No the  requirement is different totally here. no need to click any button that can be done on page load also....I need to get the current date weekly day wise in angular 8 or javascript only for 5 days related to previous and next of current day. Suppose today is saturday so it will display the date of last thursday,friday, today's date of saturday, upcoming date of sunday and monday., you can check my html for sample output

Comment: same as like wheather foecast application

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Here I need the day and date in a separate variable and I need to put like my html, but here its showing all together.

Answer (score 0):

Call this method, it will return you the array you need :-

```
function getDates(currentDate) {
 var result = [];
  for(var i = -2;i<3;i++) {
    var date = new Date(currentDate);
    result.push(new Date(date.setDate(date.getDate()+i)));
  }
  return result;
}
```